# Probability that $k$ of $n$ balls are in the same cell.

Tags: probability

> If you randomly allocate $40$ balls in $50$ cells, what's the probability that a cell contains exactly $k$ balls (with $0\leq k \leq 40$)?

I don't really know how to start.

I though all avaiable spaces are $50*40$ cause there are $50$ cells and each of them can contain maximum $40$ balls. I have $2$ types of value for each space, **1** (ball here) and **0** (ball not here). So, I can think about all *Arrangements with repetition* of $2$ elements in $50*40=2000$ positions.
Now I should remove all *Permutations* for each cell. We should have:
$$
\Omega=\frac{D^*_{2, 2000}}{50*P_{40}}
$$

I don't know what to do at this point. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of ways to distribute $40$ balls among $50$ cells is
$$50^{40}$$
and if some single cell contains $k$ of those balls, then there are 
$${49}^{40-k}$$
ways to distribute the remaining $40-k$ balls. Thus the probability should be
$$\frac{49^{40-k}}{50^{40}}$$
...am I understanding the problem correctly?

Comment: @ChuckTheYellow No problem, I'm glad to help! If you found it helpful, don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark}$!

Comment: Yes, you are. I don't know how to thank you! It's 2h30min I'm trying to figure out the solution! I'm so grateful to you! But if may I ask, why did you invert cells with balls? In my case, balls are object and cells are positions. Why did you use Arrangements with repetition of 50 cells in 40 balls?